# Spark Driver Heap Memory Issues

Tags: apache-spark

I am seeing issues where I slowly run out of Java Heap on the master node.  Below is a simple example I've created which just repeats itself 200 times.  With the settings below the master runs out of memory in about 1 hour with the following error:

```
16/12/15 17:55:46 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Launching task 97578 on executor id: 9 hostname: ip-xxx-xxx-xx-xx
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 20160"...
```

The Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark._

object MemTest {

 case class X(colval: Long, colname: Long, ID: Long)

 def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MemTest")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sc = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.getOrCreate(spark)
    import sc.implicits._;

    for( a <- 1 to 200)
    {
      var df = spark.parallelize((1 to 5000000).map(x => X(x.toLong, x.toLong % 10, x.toLong / 10 ))).toDF()
      df = df.groupBy("ID").pivot("colname").agg(max("colval"))
      df.count
    }

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

I'm running on AWS emr-5.1.0 using m4.xlarge (4 nodes+1 master). Here are my spark settings

```
{
  "Classification": "spark-defaults",
  "Properties": {
    "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "false",
    "spark.executor.instances": "16",
    "spark.executor.memory": "2560m",
    "spark.driver.memory": "768m",
    "spark.executor.cores": "1"
  }
},
{
    "Classification": "spark",
    "Properties": {
      "maximizeResourceAllocation": "false"
    }
},
```

I compile with sbt using

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.2" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.2")
```

and then run it using

```
spark-submit --class MemTest target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar
```

Looking at memory with `jmap -histo` I see `java.lang.Long` and `scala.Tuple2` keep growing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the spark version installed on the cluster is 2.0.2?

Or if there are several Spark installations on your cluster, are you sure you're calling the correct (2.0.2) spark-submit?

(I unfortunately cannot comment so that's the reason I posted this as an answer)

Comment: It is Spark 2.0.1 since that is what emr-5.1.0.  I will try emr-5.2.0.